# Why does Explorer View have to be created as public by default?

Tags: 2007, document-library, explorer-view

We have removed Explorer View from the ribbon and the list of available views for the SharePoint site's users. However the Admin users still need Explorer View. To ensue all the Admins had Explorer I got them to create a personal view and base it on the existing Explorer View. I then deleted the existing Explorer View.

When we add a new admin they can't create an Explorer view without making it public. They then have to create a personal copy of the view, then delete the public one. Is there no way to create a private Explorer view without copying a public one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there really isn't anyway to accomplish what you are wanting to do other than what you are currently doing.

With that said, removing the explorer view from the list of views does not prevent a user with access to the library from seeing the library in Windows Explorer.  So, if a user wanted to do this, its a moot point anyway.

Comment: Can you explian what you mean by it not preventing users with access seeing it in Explorer?

Comment: A user can copy the URL to the document library and navigate to it directly in Windows Explorer.  You need to disable WebDAV altogether to prevent this, but you can't do that on a per-user basis.